# How does gem5 determine whether an address is writable?

Tags: cpu, gem5

I want to check if an address is writable in gem5. This attribute appears to be recorded in the TLB.
There is a write_able variable in the TLB entry. It seems to represent whether the data can be modified by writing.

[image]

Moreover, I found where it was assigned.

[image]

And I output the result. But I found that write_able is always 1. Even for itlb.
This is so weird. Does anyone know why? Is gem5 not implementing this function? Or is there any other way to judge whether the address is write-protected?
Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: Won't it simply come from the page attributes as one would expect for an x86 simulator?

Comment: Thanks!!!   But if yes, why all write-able is 1. Even addresses translated by itlb. This should be the code.

Comment: Does your process have any read-only pages?  I'd expect an iTLB miss to still result in an accurate TLB entry (matching the page table's bit in memory), since it's only 1 extra bit per iTLB entry in a real CPU.  There can be realistic scenarios where a page is initially touched as a code miss, but later a data access to the same page happens.  (Especially for a huge/largepage, or for JITs).  It would be silly to force another page-walk on the data access because your iTLB entries effectively masked all PTEs to read-only.

Comment: Really Thanks!!!  But will data and code be placed on one page? This doesn't seem very scientific. I remember that there is a data segment and a code segment to store data and code respectively.